# Rapahel.js: Translating a set that contains an element that has already been translated

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

When trying to translate a set with Raphael the elements in that set that were created with a translate are disappearing.

I've tried both an uppercase and lowercase S to scale http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Here are the elements that aren't being translated:

```
var anotherCross = rightCross.clone().transform("T355.28 -200 R180");

var anotherCrossAgan = diagonalCross.clone().transform("T400 200 R180");
```

By:

```
groupedFlag.transform("s0.5 0.5 0 0");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomrandle/BxkGS/7/

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupedFlag.transform("...S0.5 0.5 0 0");`

Attaching `...` as prefix or postfix to your transformation string applies the transformation after or before the element's or set's current transformation respectively. (Phew! One complex sentence!)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BxkGS/11/

Comment: Thanks! That almost works. The transformed items now appear, just in the wrong place. What does the ... do?

Comment: Ahah changing the s to S does the rest. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for not providing a bit of explanation. Have edited the answer even though it seems you've figured it out. :)